# Replace certain strings with NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DF in which i need to iterate through values from two columns (location and Event) and replace the strings "Gate-3" "NO Access" with NaN.

below is the example DF.

```
Time        Location    Event               Badge ID
18:28:59    Gate-2      Access Granted      81002
18:28:12    Gate-1      Access Granted      80557
18:27:55    Gate-3      Access Granted      80557
18:27:44    Gate-3      NO Access           80398
18:25:38    Gate-1      NO Access           80978
18:25:30    Gate-2      Access Granted      73680
18:23:56    Gate-1      Access Granted      73680
18:23:52    Gate-2      Access Granted      80557
18:23:19    Gate-2      NO Access           128
18:23:16    Gate-1      Access Granted      80557
```

The expected output is

```
       Time Location           Event  Badge ID
0  18:28:59   Gate-2  Access Granted     81002
1  18:28:12   Gate-1  Access Granted     80557
2  18:27:55      NaN  Access Granted     80557
3  18:27:44      NaN             NaN     80398
4  18:25:38   Gate-1             NaN     80978
5  18:25:30   Gate-2  Access Granted     73680
6  18:23:56   Gate-1  Access Granted     73680
7  18:23:52   Gate-2  Access Granted     80557
8  18:23:19   Gate-2             NaN       128
9  18:23:16   Gate-1  Access Granted     80557
```

Comment: add NaN if "Gate-3" is found in location and if "NO Access" is found in Event column

Comment: Are you reading this from a CSV? And what is the expected output?

Comment: I am reading this from .xlsx file

Comment: That only answered half my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this up while loading your XLS file by specifying a `na_values` parameter.

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xls', na_values=['Gate-3', 'NO Access'])
print(df)

       Time Location           Event  Badge ID
0  18:28:59   Gate-2  Access Granted     81002
1  18:28:12   Gate-1  Access Granted     80557
2  18:27:55      NaN  Access Granted     80557
3  18:27:44      NaN             NaN     80398
4  18:25:38   Gate-1             NaN     80978
5  18:25:30   Gate-2  Access Granted     73680
6  18:23:56   Gate-1  Access Granted     73680
7  18:23:52   Gate-2  Access Granted     80557
8  18:23:19   Gate-2             NaN       128
9  18:23:16   Gate-1  Access Granted     80557
```

This is, IMO, better than having to clean up your data *after* loading it in.

Comment: Also OP seems to have changed the specs, AND became OR.

Comment: Thanks it looks more convenient.

Comment: @timgeb Has been a common pattern today it seems... people are not enthusiastic with having questions answered... /sigh have +1'd your answer as well, keep it up, happy to see more people taking an interest in the tag.

Comment: Thanks. A suggestion: passing a dict for the `na_values` parameter is more robust, then you can let go of the assumption that `Gate-3` can't appear in the Event column and `'NO Access'` can't appear in the Location column.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a boolean mask where your conditions are true with

```
mask = df.Location.eq('Gate-3') & df.Event.eq('NO Access') # df is your dataframe
```

You can use that mask to set whatever columns you want to `NaN` like this:

```
df.loc[mask, ['Location', 'Event']] = np.nan # imported numpy as np
```

---

edit:

It seems you have changed the specifications. If you want to set `NaN` where the Location OR Event column match your sentinel values, use two masks.

```
locmask = df.Location.eq('Gate-3')                                                                                     
df.loc[locmask, 'Location'] = np.nan                                                                                   
evmask = df.Event.eq('NO Access')                                                                                      
df.loc[evmask, 'Event'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

**If I don't misunderstood your question**, then How about this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.loc[df.Location == 'Gate-3', 'Location'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.Event == 'NO Access', 'Event'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Instead of "NAN" it would be better to set it as `np.nan` (you need to `import numpy as np` first). This would create a real NaN value.

Comment: Thanks i was thinking of some looping solution. this one liner did it.

Comment: @NielsHenkens can you show some example. It would be great.

Comment: @NielsHenkens Totally agreed with you. I thought OP want String "NAN" :)

Comment: @user10317766 I've edited my answer, Have a look now

Answer (score 0):

Iteration is not necessary to set a columns value based off of a condition. Instead you would use Boolean indexing.

**Example:**

```
data = {'Time':['18:28:59', '18:28:59', '18:28:59'], 
     'Location':['Gate-2', 'Gate-3', 'Gate-1', ], 
     'Event':['Access Granted', 'NO Access', 'NO Access'], 
     'BadgeID':[81002, 80557, 80557]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Time       Location     Event         BadgeID
0   18:28:59   Gate-2     Access Granted  81002
1   18:28:59   Gate-3     NO Access       80557
2   18:28:59   Gate-1     NO Access       80557
```

The 'loc' method is a label based indexer which accepts a boolean array, as well as other options.

The conditional expression:

```
df.Location == 'Gate-3'
```

returns a boolean array or Series

```
0    False
1    True
2    False
Name: Location, dtype: bool
```

You can check this with the built-in function type()

```
type(df.Location == 'Gate-3')
# pandas.core.series.Series
```

This series is used as the row-index for the original DataFrame's loc method.

The loc method takes a row-indexer and a column-indexer.
So the below statement

```
df.loc[df.Location == 'Gate-3', 'Location'] = np.nan
```

translates to:

> Set the intersection of the rows where the Location  is Gate-3 and the Location column to a null value